# Custom Map Tile Work in Chrome but not Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm building an Android app that uses custom map tiles. I started out with a set that worked fine but only had limited zoom levels and area. Then I switched to another tile set that covered much more area but simply refuses to display in Android. I can see them in the Javascript Maps and there are no errors in my LogCat so I'm not sure what's going on.

Are there only certain image formats that the Android Map overlays support?

For reference, here are the two tile sets:

This one works both on the web and in Android:
http://mooproductions.org/vfrs/local.html

This one works on the web but simply doesn't render on Android:
http://mooproductions.org/vfrs/national.html

Here's he code I'm using to provide the tile sets:

```
public class VfrTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider
{
//  private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.mooproductions.org/vfrs/%d/%d/%d.png";
//  private static final String BASE_URL = "http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw/%d/%d/%d.jpg";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://vfrmap.com/20170914/tiles/vfrc/%d/%d/%d.jpg";

    public VfrTileProvider (int width, int height)
    {
        super(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public URL getTileUrl (int x, int y, int zoom)
    {
        int reversedY = (1 << zoom) - y - 1;
//      String tileUrl = String.format(Locale.US, BASE_URL, zoom, x, reversedY);
        String tileUrl = String.format(Locale.US, BASE_URL, zoom, reversedY, x);
        Log.d("Tile Provider", tileUrl);
        URL url = null;

        try { url = new URL(tileUrl); }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return url;
    }
}
```

You can see commented out are the other URLs for tile sets that I use that work just fine. The creation of the tileUrl is a little different because this new tile set transposes the x and y in their url.

Here is the code I use to display the custom tiles:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    _map = googleMap;

    _map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    VfrTileProvider tileProvider = new VfrTileProvider(256, 256);
    _map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION }, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        return;
    }

    Location location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(_locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    if (location != null)
    {
        _map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
            .zoom(10)
            .build();
        _map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems issue is not in image formats, but in Android native app work with custom tile layer: seems native app can't show map of certain zoom level if there no tiles for it and cant skip that layer automatically. May be you start showing map from zoom level with no custom tiles and Google Maps engine just stuck on it (on zoom level with no custom tiles). Also, please, add some source code to better understanding of issue.

Comment: I set the zoom level of the map for a level that I know has tiles. I have also tried zooming past the tiles I have on my server and back out and then past and back in and it never gets "stuck."

Comment: In fact I even log out the url of the tiles when I build them and l can click on them and they open right up in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because wrong `"User-Agent"` property settings of `URL url` object in `VfrTileProvider.getTileUrl()`. You can set it to correct by `setRequestProperty()`:

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(tileUrl);
    try {
        url.openConnection().setRequestProperty("User-Agent","<correct user agent name>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

or just add `System.setProperty("http.agent", "");` call to your `public void onMapReady ()`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "");    
    _map = googleMap;
    ...
}
```

I prefer second (`System.setProperty("http.agent", "");`) case.

Comment: Oh my god! I NEVER would have thought of that! Thank you!